# Finding specific classes in table columns (python, lxml)

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I was thrown ("change this existing program") into python and lxml and try to find my way by doing it. 
So I am sorry for asking maybe an easy or silly question ... but I am a bit stuck.

The program is cracking a table into the rows by

```
rows=page.cssselect("table-data.table-top tbody tr")
```

The various columns are addressed (after: for row in rows) by

```
dns = row.cssselect(".column-number")
cds = row.cssselect(".column-documents")
```

However in the column `"column-documents"` there are several (maybe 0, maybe 5) entries (empty, 1 icon with link, up to 5 icons with links and different meanings, each defined with it's own class). And I need to find out, if a specific entry (icon with link) is given there.

It is described as a specific class `"class="document-link submission-link hide-text"`.

```
<tr class="row-0 tier1-5">
   <td class="column-notext">4.</td>
   <td class="column-label">Descriptive title</td>
   <td class="column-number">007</td>
   <td class="column-dokumente">
      <a href="/somelink.pdf" target="_blank" title="title of pdf">
         <span class="document-link submission-link hide-text">
            <span>Main Document</span>
         </span>
      </a>
      <a href="/somelink.pdf) title 2">
         <span class="attachment-link submission-attachment-link hide-text">
            <span>(text)</span>
         </span>
      </a>
      <a href="/link.pdf" target="_blank" title="some title">
         <span class="document-link beschluss-link hide-text">
            <span>text</span>
         </span>
      </a>
      <span class="document-spacer hide-text" />
      <a href="html-link" title="some title">
         <span class="vorgang-link hide-text">
            <span>text</span>
         </span>
      </a>
   </td>
</tr>
```

I just need to know if this is there or not.
And my silly question is: How do I do it?

Thanks in advance,
Andreas.

Comment: Why don't you select this element? (eg `tag = cds[0].cssselect('.document-link.submission-link.hide-text')`). If the element is present `tag` will be a list containing one item, if not an empty list. And you can  use it as a condition (empty lists evaluate to false) to determine if the element exists.

Comment: Excellent. That was what I needed to know. Thank'S.